# Need regex only one number in regex

Tags: php, regex

I have two types of text from that i need to extract the name

```php
1     #PRESTIGE COOKTOP 3B        6995.00/
3    #PRESTIGE SS DLX ALPHA       2250.00/
```

By using following expression I am able to extract the first one but not the second one.

I use

```php
(?'SrNo'\d+)\s+(?'Itemname'#([A-Z\s.*-]*)[\d]{1}[A-Z\s.*-]*)\s+(?'MRP'[0-9.]*)
```

Comment: Remove this part `]{1}[` See https://regex101.com/r/FNTJi0/1

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```php
(?'SrNo'\d+)\s+(?'Itemname'#(\D*?)(?:\s+(\d[A-Z\s.*-]*?))?)\s+(?'MRP'\d[\d.]*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TnCwut/1/). *Details*:

- `(?'SrNo'\d+)` - Group "SrNo": one or more digits
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces (use `\h+` if you want to stay on the same line)
- `(?'Itemname'#(\D*?)(?:\s+(\d[A-Z\s.*-]*?))?)` - Group "Itemname": `#`, Group 3: zero or more non-digit char as few as possible, then an optional occurrence of one or more whitespaces and then Group 4: a digit and then zero or more uppercase letters, whitespace, `.`, `*` or `-` chars as few as possible (maybe `.*` should be removed if you meant to match any text, or just replace `[...]` here with `.*?` to match any text)
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces (use `\h+` if you want to stay on the same line)
- `(?'MRP'\d[\d.]*)` - Group "MRP": a digit and then zero or more digits or dots.

Comment: @aniketashtekar Please check my explanation, since your `.*` inside the character class looks suspicious. Maybe `(?'SrNo'\d+)\s+(?'Itemname'#(\D*?)(?:\s+(\d.*?))?)\s+(?'MRP'\d[\d.]*)` will work even better, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TnCwut/2).

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove `]{1}[` or else you have 2 character classes where the first character has to be a digit and in the second string `ALPHA` does not start with a digit.

```
(?'SrNo'\d+)\s+(?'Itemname'#([A-Z\s.*-]*)[\d]{1}[A-Z\s.*-]*)\s+(?'MRP'[0-9.]*)
                                            ^^^^^
```

The updated pattern:

```
(?'SrNo'\d+)\s+(?'Itemname'#([A-Z\s.*-]*)[\dA-Z\s.*-]*)\s+(?'MRP'[0-9.]*)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FNTJi0/1)

Comment: 2  #Mixture 7oz/24   96.00/ for this text this is not working

Comment: @aniketashtekar like this? https://regex101.com/r/oQMEzS/1

Comment: no actually i want  #Mixture 7oz/24 this as Itemname

Comment: @aniketashtekar Here are some patterns that get the values. If the forward slash at the end is always there: 

`(?'SrNo'\d+)\s+(?'Itemname'#(.*?))\h+(?'MRP'\d[\d.]*)\/` See https://regex101.com/r/79WPdL/1 

If it always ends in a number with a dot `(?'SrNo'\d+)\s+(?'Itemname'#(.*?))\h+(?'MRP'\d+\.\d+\b)` See https://regex101.com/r/wyxkvz/1 

To allow word chars and horizontal whitespace chars in between the groups: 

`(?'SrNo'\d+)\s+(?'Itemname'#([\w\h\/]+?))\h+(?'MRP'\d[\d.]*)\b` See https://regex101.com/r/VzO8ys/1